# is $V$ Zariski dense in $K\otimes V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces

Suppose $V$ is a vector space over infinite field $k$ and $K$ an extension of $k$. If we consider $(V)_K= K \otimes V$ as a $K$-vector space then in what sense $V$ is Zariski dense in $(V)_K$?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention $k$ is infinite.

Comment: Dear @Tobias, I deleted my comment. Feel free to delete yours...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $V$ is Zariski dense in $K \otimes_k V$ **if $k$ is infinite**.
Indeed the closure of $V$ consists in the intersection $\cap_P V(P)$ of the zero sets $V(P)\subset K \otimes_k V$ for all polynomials $P\in K[T_1,\cdots,T_n]$ vanishing on $V$.
But $P$ is necessarily the zero polynomial so that $V(P)=K\otimes_k V$ and thus the Zariski closure of $V$ is indeed $K\otimes_k V$.

**Remarks**
1) The assertion on polynomials vanishing if they vanish on $V\cong k^n$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102182/polynomials-vanishing-on-an-infinite-set) .
2) The result is false for every  finite field $k$:
Indeed take $V=k^1=k$. Then for any strict field extension $k\subsetneq K$ the subset $V=k\subsetneq K\otimes _k V=K$ is finite, thus closed and thus not dense.