# If a polynomial, in $n\geq2$ variables, over an infinite field $k$, vanishes everywhere on $k^n$, is it the zero polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

For $k$ an infinite field, for integer $n\geq2$, for $p \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, if $p(\vec{a}) = 0$ for all $\vec{a} \in k^n$, then is $p$ the zero polynomial?  (Here by "infinite" field we mean a field having infinitely many elements.)

My understanding so far is as follows:

- If $k$ is algebraically closed, then $p$ is contained in all max ideals of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, but the intersection of all max ideals in this situation is 0.
- For $k = \mathbb{R}$, from analysis we know a polynomial vanishing everywhere is the zero polynomial. Similarly we can use analysis for the $k=\mathbb{Q}$ case.

(If I'm not mistaken, an example of a nonzero polynomial vanishing everywhere with $n\geq2$ but $k$ finite can be achieved by taking $\prod_{a \in k}(x_1-a)$.)

Comment: See my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2789699/zeros-of-polynomial-over-an-infinite-field/2789760#2789760

Comment: It's confusing that the question in the title (to which the answer is "no") is the opposite of the question inside (to which the answer is "yes").

Comment: This question recurs often enough. The oldest applicable thread may be [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/102182/11619). Unfortunately the answer there is in the comments. At the time users were reluctant to reproduce passages found in several textbooks *as an answer*. Standards have slipped since. I don't mind relatively new users to show their understanding by posting. Not at all. But the veterans should know :-)

Comment: @2'59'2 Thanks for noticing that, I'll edit the title to match the question inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. We proceed by induction on $n$. For $n=1$, the number of roots of a non-zero polynomial is at most its degree and in particular finite. For general $p\in k[x_1,\dots,x_n],$ we write $$p=\sum_{k=1}^m q_k(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})x_n^k.$$ If we fix $x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}$, $p$ reduces to a polynomial in one variable and the coefficients must vanish. Since this holds for any $x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}$, the $q_k$ are zero polynomials by induction hypothesis, i.e., $p=0$.